# Оптимизация запросов MySQL

Tags: mariadb, mysql

Есть большая таблица в БД, в которую поступает очень много однотипных запросов в короткий промежуток времени:

```
select username from users where id = 1;
select concat(username, ' ', password) from users where id = 1;
select username, date() from users where id = 1;
```

Из примера видно, что изменяется только сам select и постоянно возвращается одна и та же строка, но с разными столбцами.

Мне нужно сделать так:

- при первом запросе осуществляется поиск в таблице
- при последующих запросах поиск не осуществляется, а берется из кэша или из временной таблицы..., но главное, чтобы не осуществлялся поиск по таблице `users`

Как достичь подобной функциональности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем не устравает один запрос типа

```
SELECT username, concat(username, ' ', password), date() FROM users WHERE id=1
```

записать все значения в массив и обрабатывать его вообще без обращения к БД?

Comment: это, в принципе, логично, но меня интересует чисто из интереса, возможно ли сделать так, как я описал в вопросе

Comment: @nullptr, возможно, но нужен ли этот кэш, для такого простого запроса? Для БД вытащить одну строку по id весьма простая задача. Кстати, вытаскивать данные все же лучше одним запросом, как уже написали выше.

Comment: Ясно. Я понял. Спасибо.